# asterisk early media audio issue

Tags: audio, sip, asterisk, playback

I didn't get any audio in sip calling when using early media feature of asterisk.

Normally its working fine but due to playback apps, asterisk answer the sip channel and timer of user start that should not be happen.
That why I am trying to implement early media option in asterisk.
It is working as said but problem occur in audio. I could not hear anything unless user pick the phone.

extension.conf

exten => _X.,1,Progress()

exten => _X.,n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/verification,noanswer)

exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/channel/number)

sip.conf

[xxx]

fullname=xxx

type=friend

host=dynamic

disallow=all

allow=g729

allow=ulaw

allow=alaw

allow=gsm

username=xxx

secret=xxx

context=sip-calling-test

qualify=yes

call-limit=2

nat=yes

Does any one know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Early media highly depending of endpoints/provider used.

So you need use ATA with early media support or did provider with early media.